# PhantomJS not throwing onload event for iframe

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm trying to write a test (karma/mocha/chai using PhantomJS) for an iframe component we have. The component adds an iframe to the page, and resolves a promise when the iframe's `onload` event fires.

```
$('iframe').on('load', function() {
   promise.resolve();
});
```

It works fine in-browser, but the event never seems to fire when using inside PhantomJS.

I tested using an invalid the `src` and phantom threw a 404 error so I know it's loading something.

Is there any known issue with PhantomJS + onload? I can't find anything.

Is there any way to better debug this?

Comment: I think Iframe onload function only recently came to chrome/firefox/ie, I don't know if phantom supports this event yet

Comment: I just tested plain old `iframe.onload = function(){console.log("loaded")}` and it works in PhantomJS 1.9.0, 1.9.7 and 2.0.0. Either this is an SSL issue or there is a cross-domain problem for whatever reason. Try running with `--ignore-ssl-errors=true --ssl-protocol=any --web-security=false`. Also, what version are you using? Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: I'm running these tests from with Karma and the karma-phantomjs-launcher modules - so `require('webpage').create(),` isn't available to me. I'm not seeing any alternatives I can hook into from the karma-launcher.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, a PDF is being rendered in my iframe and phantomjs considers it loaded, but JS event is not firing, even with the onload="" html attribute

Comment: Did you ever find a workaround to get your tests to pass?

Comment: I don't know that I did anything, but it did wind up working. We have some promises which resolve when the `onload` event is fired and those are being resolved correctly in our tests. I recall that I specifically chose to use an invalid URL because leaving it as index.html, `/` or `#` would re-trigger the karma test runner script.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the exact same issue as you with mocha + phantom, and in my case I resolved it by setting the iframe `src` before appending it to the DOM.

```
// load event fires in browser, not in phantom
var myIframe = document.createElement('iframe');
document.body.appendChild(myIframe);
iframe.src = 'www.example.com';

// load event fires in both
var myIframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src = 'www.example.com';
document.body.appendChild(myIframe);
```